# Sorting by specific column number - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The code below sort by data on a set range

```
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 

mySheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
mySheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With mySheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:U" & lastrow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The number of columns can vary each time the code is executed. Is there a way to adapt this code so that the range uses both lastrow and lastcol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, see below adjustment (not tested), but you should get the logic.

```vb
With mySheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range(mySheet.Cells(1,1), mySheet.Cells(lastrow,lastcol))
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```